# Reading text file and omitting line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, text-files, streamreader

Is there any method of reading from a text file and omitting certain lines from the output into a text box?.

the text file will look like this

```
Name=Test Name 
Date=19/02/14
Message blurb spanning over several lines
```

The format will always be the same and the Name & Date will always be the 1st 2 rows and these are the rows that i want to omit and return the rest of the message blurb to a text box.

I know how to use the `ReadAllLines` function and `StreamReader` but not sure how to start coding it.

Any pointers or directions to some relevant online documentation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read file line by line and just skip lines with given beginnings:

```
string[] startsToOmit = new string[] { "Name=", "Date=" };

var result = File.ReadLines(path)
                 .Where(line => !startsToOmit.Any(start => line.StartsWith(start)));
```

and then you have an `IEnumerable<string>` as a `result`, you can use it for example by `result.ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks but i'm struggling with getting the result into a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the stream line by line:

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        }
```

Ignore the first two lines, and process the 3rd line however you need.